# The controllers doens't work on my spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa, java-ee-8

I don't know what is happening but im doing everything good.

The application starts well

```
[2m2023-04-22T03:23:17.326+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m55932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.alibou.security.SecurityApplication   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting SecurityApplication using Java 17.0.6 with PID 55932 (D:\Descargas\spring-boot-3-jwt-security-main\spring-boot-3-jwt-security-main\target\classes started by luis_ in D:\Descargas\spring-boot-3-jwt-security-main\spring-boot-3-jwt-security-main)
[2m2023-04-22T03:23:17.328+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m55932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.alibou.security.SecurityApplication   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
[2m2023-04-22T03:23:18.034+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m55932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
[2m2023-04-22T03:23:18.042+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m55932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardService  [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting service [Tomcat]
[2m2023-04-22T03:23:18.042+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m55932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.4]
[2m2023-04-22T03:23:18.128+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m55932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]      [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
[2m2023-04-22T03:23:18.128+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m55932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mw.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 761 ms
[2m2023-04-22T03:23:18.436+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m55932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mo.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
[2m2023-04-22T03:23:18.444+02:00[0;39m [32m INFO[0;39m [35m55932[0;39m [2m---[0;39m [2m[           main][0;39m [36mc.alibou.security.SecurityApplication   [0;39m [2m:[0;39m Started SecurityApplication in 1.412 seconds (process running for 1.872)
```

this is the main class

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan("com.alibou.security.user")
public class SecurityApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SecurityApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

and this is the structure of the project

[image]

this is one controller sample

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

    @GetMapping("/hello")
    public String helloWorld() {
        return "Hello World";
      }
}
```

and this is an input from POSTMAN

[image]

nothing is working, i swear i didnt have this problems years ago, now even the most simple thing is not working anymore.

Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Baeldung has a good explanation on how these annotations work here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning.

Essentially, (from their site):

> We use the @SpringBootApplication annotation, but it's a combination of three annotations:
>
> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableAutoConfiguration
> @ComponentScan
> ```
>
> Only the location of the configuration class matters, as component scanning starts from its package by default.

Since you have used the `@SpringBootApplication`, the scanning will start from there, so I dont think you need to have the `@ComponentScan` annotation here. Unless you are trying to achieve something else that you did not mention on the question.

Comment: i have 4 years experience in springboot, i've been experience this since 1 year ago, i don't know whe autowired annotations gives errors, the respositories, the services, its like eclipse is having a hard time trying to scan this components, your @EnableAutoConfiguration really worked for me, is incredible. thank you bro for real.

Answer (score 1):

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = {DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class, SecurityAutoConfiguration.class})
@ComponentScan("com.alibou.security")
public class SecurityApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SecurityApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Use the above code, it will work. Refer here [Spring Component Scanning](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning)